# Non-linear translation invariant functionals on $L^1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, calculus-of-variations

I have recently come across a class of (possibly non-linear) operators $F$ defined on $L^1$ such that

1. $F \colon L^1(\mathbb R^d) \to \mathbb [0,+\infty]$;
2. $F(u(\cdot - z)) = F(u(\cdot))$ for every $u \in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$, $z \in \mathbb R^d$.

> **Q.** Does there exist a characterization of the class of functions $F$ satisfying satisfying Conditions (1) and (2)?

For instance, it seems to me that all functionals of the form $F(u)=\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(u(x),\nabla u(x))\,dx$ - being $f \colon \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ a given non-negative function - enjoy (1) and (2), thanks to the translation-invariance of the Lebesgue measure.

Are there other functionals besides these ones? Does the answer change is we add the restriction that the functional $F$ has an integral representation?

Comment: As a stupid remark, the $F$ you indicate is not defined on $L^1$ since it involves derivatives of $f$ which do not exist a priori.

Comment: Yeah, I did not underline it but $F$ may take value $+\infty$: so the expression written above would be the definition of $F$ if $u \in W^{1,1}$ (or $BV$ with some abuse), with the convention that $F=+\infty$ elsewhere... Thanks in any case for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fourier transform (it has been invented for that). Call $\hat{u}(k)$, $k\in \mathbb{R}^d$ the Fourier transform of $u$, for example any function depending only on the absolute value of $|\hat{u}|$ is fine $$F(u)=G(|\hat{u}|) $$
Indeed, your condition is weaker and is equivalent to $F(u)=G(\hat{u})$ where $G(e^{i\theta} \hat{u})=G(\hat{u})$ for any $\theta\in \mathbb{R},u\in L^1$

Comment: That sounds right. Yet, given a function $F$, how do you find the related function $G$? Let me take the simple example
$$
F(u) = \|u\|_{L^1}
$$